# Bundles and Virtual Paths

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am setting up a new site using angular, mvc and web api.  The static content (js, css, images, etc) will be in Site A, the MVC site will be in Site B and the api will be in Site C.  These are all separate sites, not virtual directories.  I'm trying to use bundling in the MVC site to bundle the js and css files from the static site for use in the MVC site.

I've set up a Virtual Path Provider but when I load the site angular doesn't work and also doesn't throw any errors.  I'm assuming that the angular.js file is not being loaded from the bundle because if I include a local javascript file angular works.

Is what I want to do possible?  If so, how?

Comment: You may be having cross-domain issues as well. I'm not sure of the nuances but if your scripts, views and API are all on different domains the browser may be very sad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtual Path Providers only apply to views, not things like CSS and JS. Unfortunately, there's not really a good way to handle this scenario. The bundler can only act on files within the same project, not those in a separate project. If you want a separate site to handle your static assets, then you pretty much just have to resort to referencing them directly. You can use the Web.config's app settings section to set the base URL for your static site (that way you have just one place to go if you need to change it later and you can do things like run transforms on it to have a different value in production). This also means you're *somewhat* on your own for bundling and minification. However, you can make your static site an MVC site as well just to get the bundling infrastructure and then use *that* site to handle bundling. All your bundles should be at the standard location of `/Content/[style bundle name].css` or `/bundles/[script bundle name].js`. There's a cache busting string added to the path, but you can somewhat handle that manually.

Comment: While this answer is essentially correct, you can use Virtual Path Providers for both CSS and JS. You need to ensure those requests are handled by ASP.NET by using the StaticFileHandler in the handlers section of web.config. You can't do cross-site virtual paths of course.